# What is a word that describes both giving something and also the receiver accepting it?

Tags: word-request

I have another question that seems to me stupid, but I can't answer it with confidence. When you collect recyclables, then arrive at a special place, and then *hand it over* (whether in exchange for payment or not), what do you call it? 'Surrender' doesn't work, 'take out' doesn't work, 'hand over' only refers to the physical act of transferring things (whereas I want to imply that it has been accepted, not just that it physically ended up in the hands of a recycling person). It's almost funny, but I struggle to find a good word for this. We have a word 'сдавать' in Russian. It means you *hand something over*, and it's *accepted* (luggage, essay, anything). So I need some corresponding term.

Comment: I don't really see a problem with **hand over**.  How can something be handed over if the recipient has not accepted it?

Answer (score 1):

[**Transfer**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transfer) might be the best word for what you want, because it's very generic but implies that the handoff has been completed.

> 1a : to convey from one person, place, or situation to another
> 1b : to cause to pass from one to another

Comment: "Transfer recyclables"? Sounds wrong

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev  It would help if you could make a sentence showing how you want to use the word.  There are plenty of uses of "transfer recyclables", like ["Republic Services' collecting trucks can transfer recyclables to semi-trucks"](https://www.thespectrum.com/story/news/2019/09/09/recycling-washington-county-landfill/2233389001/), but it depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly already mentioned the word you're looking for:

> **accepted**

The words you're having trouble with are from the givers perspective, whereas you want a word from the person receiving's perspective.